# mean over diagonal axis in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I'm trying to get the mean from a dataframe of the diagonal axis

```
            2015-08-31  2015-09-30  2015-10-31  2015-11-30  2015-12-31  \
createdat                                                                
2015-08-31    1.333333   12.555556   10.444444    5.888889    5.888889   
2015-09-30    0.000000    6.777778    4.111111    1.000000    5.333333   
2015-10-31    0.000000    0.000000    5.000000   12.312500    9.937500   
2015-11-30    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    1.909091   14.000000   
2015-12-31    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    6.760000
```

So in effect I'd like to get the mean of  1.333333 + 6.777778 + 5.000000 +1.909091

and subsequent the mean of 12.555556 + 4.111111 + 12.312500

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`np.diag`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html). For the main diagonal, this is simply

```
np.diag(df).mean()
```

and you can shift above or below the main diagonal with the `k` parameter.

If you were determined to get say, all of the primary diagonals, you could just apply the same approach with something like

```
{i: np.diag(df, i).mean() for i in range(-1*(df.shape[0]-1), df.shape[1])}
```

**Demo**

```
>>> df
   0  1  2
0  6  1  7
1  4  9  8
2  0  3  9

>>> np.diag(df).mean()
8.0

>>> np.diag(df, k=1).mean()
4.5

>>> {i: np.diag(df, i).mean() for i in range(-1*(df.shape[0]-1), df.shape[1])}
{-2: 0.0, -1: 3.5, 0: 8.0, 1: 4.5, 2: 7.0}
```